# Swift Alamofire get data to equal

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

Hi Im get json data with Alamofire and get like this:

```
{
     "prices": [
{
  "id": 1,
  "value": 1.327,
  "stationId": 24,
  "type": 0,
  "score": 5
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "value": 1.319,
  "stationId": 25,
  "type": 0,
  "score": 4
},...],

      "stations": [
{
  "id": 24,
  "name": "...",
  "address": "...",
  "brandId": 1,
  "location": ".."
},
{
  "id": 25,
  "name": "..",
  "address": "..",
  "brandId": 1,
  "location": ".."
},..],

         "brands": [
{
  "id": 6,
  "name": "AGIP"
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "name": "EKO"
}, ...]
```

How can I get all data with "type": 0

And then when get all data with type compare id from prices stations and brands  and put to array or dictionary

Answer (score 0):

You could map your response using this pod [AlamofireObjectMapper](https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/AlamofireObjectMapper) and then you can filter this object using `for` cycle.